# Error. An error occurred while processing your request. Deployment of website with database on Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, web

Error.
An error occurred while processing your request

this message appears after deploying a website ( Framework used ASP.NET 4.5.2) using Azure app services. I have followed the documentation given in the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase

I also came across this link  and followed the documentation (thinking using a different steps will resolve the error)

Please help

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I am unable to locate the error. Tried multiple options but just don't know where is the error. The error is with Database pages which are not showing
I also tried this

but still does not show the database pages. Unable to track the reason for error where is the error. Please help where seems the error

The error message

There is already an object named 'Funds' in the database. Description:

An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is already an object named 'Funds' in the database.

Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below

This is the error showing on run time. When i on local server this error does not appear and the website runs perfectly fine. But when i publish this error appears.
Yes there is a table called Funds but there is only one table in the database. Also when I run application on local server and dont get this error.

I resolved the above error but got a new error. 
Its showing database error like - Duplicate column in table where as when i open the table, i dont find any duplicate table. Also the error is not shown when i run the application on local server. 
How to resolve this. Any idea

Comment: Have you tried this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug)?

Comment: Hello Jerry Liu, thanks for your reply. No but if you have any idea.resolving the error than please let me know as not will be very helpful

Comment: The tutorial shows how to locate the error. Have a try and update your post with detailed error info. Then we can try to find specific solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks Jerry I will do that many thanks for this help

Comment: This is the error showing on run time. When i on local server this error does not appear and the website runs perfectly fine. But when i publish this error appears

Comment: Please check whether you have created a object like a table called 'Funds' in the database. If your code creates it eveytime, you will meet this error. By the way, you should update your question instead of putting it in the comment.

Comment: Sorry I am new to programming and stack Overflow. Many thanks Jerry for your help. Yes there is a table called Funds but there is only one table. Also when I run application on IIS this error does not come. How to resolve this. Any idea

Comment: Never mind. The error has changed.Try to debug it based on your code. After that, if it can't be solved, update your question with necessary code snippet and stack trace.